# Running Knife with --node-name tries to authenticate with that node_name

Tags: chef-infra, knife

The docs for knife say that --node-name is the name of the node to be configured (added to server list of nodes).  When I put in "node2", I get a message:

Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "node2"

When I use my chef user name it works.  But then my node in the server list of nodes is the user name as well.

I'm missing something pretty basic - can someone help me understand what's going on?

Here's the command I'm using:

```
# Fails
knife bootstrap myfqdn:port --ssh-user myrootname --ssh-password mypassword --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name node2 --run-list 'myrunlist'

# works, sort of
knife bootstrap myfqdn:port --ssh-user myrootname --ssh-password mypassword --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name mychefusername --run-list 'myrunlist'
```

Comment: What else does the error say, or is that it?

Comment: The "node-name" is the name of the node on the chef server and defaults to the server hostname. I wonder if your error is explained by the node already existing? Try and delete the node ("knife node delete") and see if that fixes the problem. If not you'll have to post your error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think "node2" is already registered in your Chef-Server. Node Name must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Node names must be unique when specified within the client.rb or knife.rb file wherever you are doing so. This will ensure that the chef-server has only one instance with that particular node name and doesn't hold several instances within the chef-server by the same name. So try changing the node-name and try running this. This should work.

Hope this helps,

Regards

Akshay